# Typo3 8.7.31 & extension fe_manager: No TypoScript found

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

In my TYPO3 8.7.31 I have an error:

```
No TypoScript found. Did you already setup module.tx_femanager.settings.configPID in your PageTS?
```

[image]

Comment: And? "Did you already setup module.tx_femanager.settings.configPID in your PageTS?"
https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/6.1/en-us/Installation/Index.html#configuration

Comment: Hello Julian Hofmann, thank you very much for your help. I do not know where to find this file because I have never used to work with Typo 3. Is it on FTP server or can I find it in Admin Panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to configure `module.tx_femanager.settings.configPID` in your Page TSConfig (not to confuse with TypoScript). This is necessary to make the TypoScript setting available also in the TYPO3 backend which is not the case by default.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/6.1/en-us/Installation/Index.html#configuration) you need to specify the page id (pid), where your main TypoScript settings (frontend) are stored. Usually you will take the root page of your installation.

To set the Page TSConfig, edit the page properties of your root page and switch to the tab `Resources`. There you can find a field `Page TSConfig`. In this field you need to put above mentioned setting.

A hint for your next question: please put more effort into your question! Let us know what you tried so far. And please do a proper formatting of your question.

Comment: Hello Peter Kraume, thank you very much for helping, I will try it out. ***Page TSConfig (not to confuse with TypoScript). This is necessary to make the TypoScript setting available also in the TYPO3 backend which is not the case by default.*** - Where i can find this part? On my FTP Server? This part i did not understand very well. Sorry for such  questions, but I'm completely new in Typo3.

Comment: Just do the changes in the page properties. That's done in the TYPO3 backend if you edit a page (not the content).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem can also appear, if you have set the

```
module.tx_femanager.settings.configPID = 1
```

in your root page ts
but not included the main settings (femanager) in the template.